# building a array/object in a nunjucks loops

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

I have the following in my nunjucks file,

```
{% set inProgressJobs = [] %}
{% for job in jobs %}
 {% set inProgressJobs = (setProgressJobs.push([
    {
         text: "<b><a href="">{{ job.jobTitle}}</a></b>"
    }
 ]), inProgressJobs) %}
```

When I use this in by view I would expect to see `Web Designer` but I am actually seeing `{{ job.jobTitle }}` how I interprolate my var into the text attribute?

Comment: Use a template literal maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You try to coding inside a template. It's a possible (see below) but out of template ideology. Try to put necessary logic to filters and global functions.

```
const nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
const env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('print', console.log); // for debug

const html = env.renderString(`
    {% set arr = [] %}
    {% for i in range(1, 10) %}
        {{ '' if arr.push(i) }} {# arr.push always returns non-zero so result will be '' #}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ arr | print }} {# print arr to console #}
`);
// console.log(html); // html is a pack of spaces and tabs
```